# Code First Migrations - File Name

Tags: entity-framework-migrations

We are using EF code first migrations but having an issue with the filename that gets created. We notice that it is appending the date and time to the beginning of our migration name when scaffolding changes and creating a new migration. This causes our migrations to be out of order when having to add a patch migration (in release) and then merge that into our dev branch. IE the patch will be after the new migrations in the dev branch due to the date in the file name, but we need them to appear and be ran in a specific order.

Is there any way to turn off the date that gets appended to the beginning of the migration file name and have it just use the actual name of the migration?

I've tried renaming the file and the reference to the name in the designer but that doesn't work because it prompts me to re-scaffold the changes again.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I've also found that if I create the migration in release branch, run the update-database command and then merge the migration into our dev branch when we run dev it tries to apply the same migration again (even though it's already been applied). Seems like I'm just not understanding how to properly merge this stuff across branches or keep them in the correct order.

Comment: Seen [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481501(v=vs.113).aspx)?

Comment: Yes, I have thanks Steve. It does not really address the issue I'm referring to with the timestamp that gets appended. My issues are with creating a migration in our release branch (as a patch) while also having new migrations in the dev branch. The patch migration is out of order due to the datestamp it appends and we need to keep migrations in a specific order.

Comment: I think, in theory, you might be able to do it programmatically with dbmigrator. Pseudo code would be to GetPendingMigrations, loop through them trimming off the time prefix and saving to a list, then loop through that sorted list and apply them or skip them in your desired order. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13155292/ignore-pending-migrations-after-database-recreation).

Comment: That's a good idea Steve, sorry it's taken me so long to get back to this post. I'm going to give that a try and will update once I've gotten time to verify it. Seems like you should be able to do it that way though.

Answer (score 0):

one way to get rid of this naming is somehow to add your own naming automatically. I used to use the command prompt file (.cmd) to create a name automatically (including date and time). Doing so I just need to double-click the .cmd file and the migration with my own automatic file name will be performed.
here is my .cmd file content (for example add_migrations_Identity.cmd):

```
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c_%%a_%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME: =0%") do (set mytime=%%a%%b)
dotnet ef --startup-project MyProject migrations add Identity_V%mydate%_%mytime% -o Migrations/Identity -c IdentityContext
pause
```

and here my update .cmd file (as an example update_db_Identity.cmd):

```
dotnet ef --startup-project MyProject database update -c IdentityContext
pause
```